# Mockito Test Case for Custom Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I am testing return values in a method but need to also test exceptions.
Below is a code snippet of one of the exceptions - how should I test this ?

```
  @Override
    public Response generateResponse(Request request) throws CustomException {           

        try {
            GenerateResponse response = client.generateResponse(headers, generateRequest);
            return response;
        } catch (FeignException.BadRequest badRequest) {
          String message = "Received Bad Request";
            throw new CustomException(message, "" + badRequest.status());
        } catch (FeignException.Unauthorized unauthorized) {
            log.error(unauthorized.contentUTF8());
            String message = "Received UnAuthorized Exception ";
            throw new CustomException(message, "" + unauthorized.status());
        } 
}}
```

I have tested the happy path for the method I am testing using the following:

```
Mockito.when(service.getResponse(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(getResponse);
```

Comment: Is your CUT (class under test) throwing the exception or is your CUT handling the exception?

Comment: It’s throwing the exception

Comment: If your CUT is throwing the exception, then what exactly are you trying to mock? Use `assertThatCode(() -> ...).isInstance(...)` of AssertJ for example to assert exceptions. Mockito mocks will not help you here (but you have to show a full [mre] for anybody to be able to help, which must at least include: method throwing the exception, try/catch around the method call, the test case, the test setup, …)

Comment: Thanks, I updated post to include method and the exceptions Im trying to test

Comment: Great. Now what exactly do you want to test? That `???.generateResponse` will throw a `CustomException`? Or that `client.generateResponse` throws one of two exceptions? Or that callers of `???.generateResponse` will handle the exception?

Comment: I want to test that feing exceptions badRequest and unauthorized get caught and return appropriate message through custom exception

Comment: Then you do not want to mock `service.generateResponse`, because this is the method you are trying to test. You want to set up your `client` to throw an exception, then run your service method, and eventually assert that your service method wraps the exceptions in a RuntimeException. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something? (It's also quite confusing that your client method and your calling method have the same name)

Answer (score 0):

`Mockito.when(service.getResponse(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenThrow(new CustomException());`

If you want the mock to throw an error, you do not want thenReturn but thenThrow